# Is there a way to search for a keyword in the title / body of your own questions / answers only?

Tags: feature-request, searching, search

Is there a way do a search in your own questions and specify keywords contained in the title. The same function for answers, would be usefull. As wellas to only search in the title or only in the body.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically for your issue, the search parts you want:

```
user:me
title:'Title search'
body:'Body search' 
is:answer
is:question
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to give a graphical expression to what [Grace Note](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/22665/grace-note) said before in a comment:

Let's say I want to search "flash" in my own posts:

- click own username and in the search field already appears user id

[image]

- just put the search term beside that

[image]

And **[there](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user:47206%20flash)** you go!

Of course, this works for other users: clicking their name displays their id in the search field, just add the term you want beside to see their posts on that .

Answer (score 1):

Damn I hate it when this happens: https://askubuntu.com/search
Never saw it. Sorry.

Anyway it would be nice if there was a **search field** on the users profile each in the questions and answers section.

Comment: More specifically `user:41 keyword keyword` where you replace 41 with your user id. :)

Comment: `user:me` is quicker for most people.

Comment: When you are visiting any user profile, it automatically adds to `user:id` the start of the search string with the ID of the profile you are looking at.